# Group row data from a 2d array by one column and sum another column within each group

Tags: php, arrays, sum, grouping

This feels like a duplicate but I've run through a lot of similar questions and can't quite make the solution fit my problem.

I have the following arrays which I want to group by 'SECTOR' and then sum on 'MCAP' keys.

```
[
    ["TICKER" => "ABC", "SECTOR" => 30, "MCAP" => 1000],
    ["TICKER" => "XYZ", "SECTOR" => 30, "MCAP" => 500],
    ["TICKER" => "ASD", "SECTOR" => 25, "MCAP" => 750]
]
```

And what I need to make happen is this:

```
[
    30 => ['MCAP' => 1500],
    25 => ['MCAP' => 750],
]
```

I have tried using foreach loop and best I've managed is to sum all the MCAP values. I can't wrap my head around it and would appreciate your help with the challenge.

Edit: This is what I tried :

```
$sector = array();

foreach ($stocks as $row) {
    $sum += $row['MCAP'];
    $sector[$row['SECTOR']]['MCAP'] = $sum;
}
```

But the outcome is this:

```
[
    30 => ['MCAP' => 1500],
    25 => ['MCAP' => 2250]
]
```

Comment: you want to sum only the first two MCAP ?

Comment: So show us what have you tried!

Comment: "I have tried using ..."  You should show this attempt as well as the result.

Comment: There can be any number of arrays, but I want to sum the MCAP of each array that has the same SECTOR and then output it into a new array with that key.

Comment: **Pro tip:** Beginners are welcome, but we expect a certain amount of effort to be expended on a question prior to a question being posted. 
We dont write code for you although we are very willing to help you fix issues with code you have written. Or you will have to wait for a rep hound

Comment: I appreciate it guys, still far from thinking intuitively about these problems. But I am working on it and will pose better questions soon. Thank you for your suggestions and help.

Comment: Your desired output asks for an array of unnecessary complexity.  Why not a flat associative array of `SECTOR => MCAP` pairs?  https://3v4l.org/Trapm  Mohammed's answer is the only one that generates NOTICES/WARNINGS (in other words, it is the worst answer). @Ante

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to sum using the the sector value like this way :

```
$res = array();
foreach($data as $key=> $value){
  $res[$value['SECTOR']] += $value['MCAP'];
}

var_dump($res);
```

Output:

```
Warning: Undefined array key 30

Warning: Undefined array key 25
array(2) {
  [30]=>
  int(1500)
  [25]=>
  int(750)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the array, and check if the current `SECTOR` key exists in the result-array. If it doesn't, define it to zero. Then add the current value of `MCAP` to the result-array.

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $key=> $value) {
    if (!isset($result[$value['SECTOR']]))
        $result[$value['SECTOR']]['MCAP'] = 0;
    $result[$value['SECTOR']]['MCAP'] += $value['MCAP'];
}
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create another empty array to save the `sum`. When you loop, you can create each `section` and sum the value of `mcap`:

```
$arraySum = array();

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if (!isset($arraySum[$value['SECTOR']]))
        $arraySum[$value['SECTOR']] = $value['MCAP'];
    else
        $arraySum[$value['SECTOR']] += $value['MCAP'];
}

print_r($arraySum);
```

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense to group and sum your row data into a flat, associative array because the `MCAP` key doesn't add any value to the structure.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/tmnep))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as ['SECTOR' => $s, 'MCAP' => $m]) {
    $result[$s] = ($result[$s] ?? 0) + $m;
}
var_export($result);
```

If you need to have the `MCAP` keys, then adjust the loop body to: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/v3knT))

```
$result[$s]['MCAP'] = ($result[$s]['MCAP'] ?? 0) + $m;
```